# How to cast long to string?

Tags: php

I need to cast a tweet id, which is a long, to a string. For instance, I have:

`$id = 39685855740174336;`

But `var_dump($id)` prints `float(3.9685855740174E+16)`.

I tried to get the string value using `strval()`:

`var_dump(strval($id));`

but I get `string(19) "3.9685855740174E+16"`.

What I expect is:

`string(17) "39685855740174336"`.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works for me (see the list of [string format specifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)):

```
$string_id = sprintf('%.0f', $id);
```

Basically you treat it as a float, which in PHP it is, but ask `sprintf()` not to include any decimal places.

Comment: I don't think it works, for example formatting 4862054597045407610 will return 4862054597045407744

Comment: It does not work because it will round the number, in my example 17841546856114299 became 17841546856114300

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create the value as a string:

```
$id = '39685855740174336';
```

If you are getting the value from another source such as POST or GET, the data should come in as a string to start with.

Comment: If the tweet ID is coming as JSON it's a number. That is specified by the API, so hardcoding wouldn't be a solution.

Answer (score -1):

Try `$string_id = (string)$id;`

Comment: That also yields the number in scientific notation.