# Sending signals to process via php

Tags: php, shell

I am trying to send a kill -10 (SIGUSER1) to a process ID by using a button in a webpage, I have tried different ways to send the signal while passing the PHP variable (which holds the PID) to shell. Below is what I have:

```
$next = posix_kill($pid3, 10);
```

Right now, this is giving me the below error:

```
PHP Warning:  posix_kill() expects parameter 1 to be long, 
              string given in /var/www/parse2.php on line 15
```

Please advise

Comment: Ok, so whats on line 15 of the php script at /var/www/parse2.php? Try echo $pid3 ...

Comment: -_- line 15 is the: $next = posix_kill($pid3, 10);
Also i did add echo "$pid3"; and it echo's correctly

Comment: Then it is what it says it is, $pid3 is a string ...  Not a long...

Comment: use var_dump() to check the type/content right before calling posix_kill..

Comment: try casting it: `(long)`

Comment: Glenn, I added var_dump($pid3) and here is the output: 3375 string(28). "3375" is the PID, how can i change this to an int instead of a str?

Comment: Ok, just cast it.  That is an int.   So you put (long) in fron of it. It's probably since it comes from the shell that it is a string.

Comment: He needs a long, not an int.

Comment: @GlennPlas - I know. `;)`

Comment: Great feedback guys! Only thing is, when I use long as a cast, I get a syntax error: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$pid3' (T_VARIABLE)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just try this:

```
$next = posix_kill((long)$pid3, 10);
```

[Intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) returns an int so the warning won't go away, but it will probably work

So since you seem to have a problem still better would be like suggested elswhere:

```
$next = posix_kill(intval($pid3), 10);
```

If that doesn't work I'd suggest to show us the php version you use.

Unless you have a space that comes with it, then try:

```
$next = posix_kill(intval(trim($pid3)), 10);
```

update:

So now you got it working, you need to trap the signal and make it do something, you need to attach a callback function, since I don't know the rest of your code.  You need something like this :

```
pcntl_signal(SIGUSR1, "sig_handler");
```

Then do something on that signal:

```
function sig_handler($sig) {

   switch($sig) {
      case SIGUSR1:
         // logtrace(1,"received USR1 signal.");
         break;
   ...
```

I just think about 1 thing, I assume that the process we are sending a signal is a PHP script.  Otherwise I think you got it working but isn't doing a whole lot (yet)

Comment: When I use that, I get a syntax error: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$pid3' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: do it as suggested elsewhere, try intval().  Apparantly [posix_kill](http://php.net/manual/en/function.posix-kill.php) expects an int, it's strange that it says it needs a long.

Comment: Great, I get downvoted by someone..  Tx for telling me why. Trying to help someone ...

Comment: Hey Glenn, I tried the last suggestion in this answer just to test if there was an extra space with it, everything seems to be working, except the PID is not getting the signal. Only thing that returns is this: "3375"
User defined signal 1
Also, my version of php is 5.4.6

Comment: idk who downvoted you but they need to stop and go somewhere else. You seem to be the only one who is actually trying to help someone around here... trolls

Comment: @xxethanixx - This just occurred to me, what is `$pid3`? If you `echo` it, is it a string?

Comment: @JaredFarrish yes it is a string when echo'd:
3375 string(28) "

Comment: @xxethanixx - You mean the `3375 string(28)` was all together, from `echo $pid3;`?

Comment: Also, to answer @GlennPlas' question, apparently Zend makes all `int`s `long`. Or something.

Comment: Tx Jared, I didn't know that.

Comment: @xxethanixx : It looks like it's working now. You probably need to trap the signal and make it do something, since it's a user_defined signal, I usually use kill -1 (SIGHUP) to send the process a signal. (I updated my answer)

Comment: @GlennPlas Thanks for following up!!!! Much appreciated! There isn't much more to my code because I am just making a next button for ezstream/icecast. This code will be ran when I push a button(via website) to next a song. I have a question with the sig_handler function. Is this meant to go in the same source file, and is it sopposed to go before the $next = posix_kill(intval(trim($pid3)), 10);?

Comment: It's php function, so normal php rules apply.  You can include them in an external file, but it makes sense to put it in the same file.  So, functions in PHP can be put at the top/bottom of a file, as long as it is defined somewhere.  It just depends on what you are sending a signal, so if that is a running PHP script, it has to be available  there.

Answer (score 5):

most php functions will try to coerce their arguments into the appropriate data type if its possible. its extremely common for php functions to automatically convert strings into numeric types like int or float, if possible.

But, some just aren't written that way, and you need to supply the data type specified in the manual.

"long" is a numeric type, so just cast to integer. This assumes $pid3 is a numeric string, so that the cast results in something sensible.

```
$next = posix_kill((int) $pid3, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can convert it to int then it should work:

```
$next = posix_kill((int)$pid3, 10);
```

Your vairable is a string or anything else.

or try this:

[How to cast long to string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067169/how-to-cast-long-to-string)

Comment: Umm. You got something backwards there. `8|`